# Why log4j root logger does not pick up the changes I made to one of its appenders?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a java program that will scan log files every hour and sends email to IT when it detects an error. The logger is configured using log4j.properties file.

Now, I want to change the recipient of the email at run time. The code looks like this:

```
SMTPAppender smtp = (SMTPAppender)(logger.getAppender("smtp"));
smtp.activateOptions();
smtp.setTo(email);
logger.removeAppender("smtp");  // I tried it with or without the two lines
logger.addAppender(smtp);       // It's the same result
```

When I debug it, I can see on the stack that the To field of smtp is indeed the email address I want, but when I call `logger.error(message);` later it still sends to the email address specified in the configuration file.

Can anyone give me an idea why this is happening? I know I can create smtp appender all at run time programmatically but I wonder if there's a way to mix programmatic configuration and properties file configuration.